# Evaluate $\oint_{C}\frac{e^z}{(z-i)^2(z+2)}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

> $$\oint_{C}\frac{e^z}{(z-i)^2(z+2)}dz\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,C:|z-i|=2$$

My try:

Let's denote $f(z):=\frac{e^z}{(z+2)}$ Applying Cauchy's integral formula: $$=\oint_{C}\frac{\frac{e^z}{(z+2)}dz}{(z-i)^2}=f'(i)2\pi\cdot i=\boxed{\frac{e^i(1+i)}{(i+2)^2}\cdot 2\pi i}$$

I'm not sure if my attempt is correct or not.

Comment: The curve $|z-i| = 2$ passes through $z = -i$, which is a singularity of the integrand. Are you sure you have the problem written down correctly?

Comment: $(0,1)$  is the center of the circle, the radius is $2$, right?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 do you mean $z=\color{red}+i$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 ohh yes, typo

Comment: In the integral you have $(z+i)^2$ in the denominator. So the singularity is at $z = -i$.

Comment: Yes, i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. You can even use the residue theorem. The only singularity inside C is $z = i$. The residue at that point is
\begin{equation}
\frac{i + 1}{(i + 2)^2}e^{i}
\end{equation}
The integral, therefore, evaluates to
\begin{equation}
2\pi i\frac{i + 1}{(i + 2)^2}e^{i}
\end{equation}